# UK visit visa refused due to suspected funds parking. Best strategy to re-apply?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, saudi-arabia

[image: My refusal letter-my husband did not receive any]My husband had planned to attend a training program in London later in October this year, and he had applied for a Business Visit Visa from Riyadh, KSA. Me and my daughter applied along with him as General Visitors. My husband had attended a training program in London in 2014 as well at the same institute, and we had accompanied him on his visit. We stayed in London for 10 days. That was the first time, me and my daughter received UK visa, whereas my husband had traveled to UK before in 2008 as well, on Business Visit Visa, and had stayed there for about 3 months. That visa was granted from Islamabad, Pakistan. So we do have a history of past travel and compliance.

We were quite sure that our visa will be approved this time around as well, but it was refused. My envelope and my daughters' contained a letter of refusal. Her stated that since her parents had not been granted a visa, her application was being refused as well. Mine stated that since I was dependent on my husband, my visa could not be granted either. It also stated that his was refused because of a substantial amount transferred into his account before the application, which was other than his salary. That amount was transferred by his employer as a performance bonus. We were not aware of the 'PARKING' strategy, and did not attach any evidence of where that transfer came from. Therefore the visa officer was not sure of his financial status, and did not consider him to be a genuine visitor. My husband also has another bank account, in which he keeps his savings. He had not attached a bank statement related to that account thinking of it as unnecessary. He had not attached any evidence of his savings account in his previous application either which got approved.

Also, his envelope did not contain anything other than his passport. There was no letter of refusal. And me and my daughter had a black box stamped on the last page of our passports, which said UK/Riyadh, and had a number hand written on top. His passport did not contain any such stamp. We got to know that his was refused from the letter that came with my passport.

Now his employer wants him to register for the same course in December, and re-apply for the visa. He is going to obtain a letter from the company, endorsing all the extra transfers in his salary account, other than his monthly salaries. He is also planning to attach the bank statement of his savings account, along with that of his salary account. Will they want to know why he did not mention his other account in the previous application? My husband earns well, and we have been settled in Riyadh for about 6 years now. Is there anything else we need to attach with the application this time? We did enclose the invitation letter, letter from the company indicating his designation and salary, our marriage certificate and our daughters'birth certificate. We attached all those documents, that we did last time when our visa got approved. So I assume there was no short-coming in that regard. But now that we have been refused the visa once, I have heard our applications will be undergo stricter scrutiny. Will it take longer than usual now? The next session for the training starts on 7th December, so can we expect an outcome before that? Any suggestions in this regard will be really helpful.

Comment: You should have been given a refusal letter that would cite why you were refused. We need to know what was on that to know the exact grounds of refusal. Can you please edit your question to include that?

Comment: The edited question now looks to [be a duplicate of this question here on provenance of funds](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking), but I can't vote to close as a duplicate so someone else will need to!

Comment: @Gagravarr, indeed it's nearly a duplicate, but this OP has some additional stuff and was referred to a new question by the OP of the original question. I can give a brief answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is prompted by this exchange of comments between you and a person who was refused for a similar reason...

> @mayasheikh. Our application has recently been rejected for similar
>   reasons. My husband had applied in the Business Visit Category,
>   whereas we had applied General Visitor for myself and my daughter. He
>   received a performance bonus a few months ago, and that led to the
>   refusal. I am also a Pakistani based in Riyadh. My husband has visited
>   the UK twice before, whereas me and my daughter had visited the UK
>   once, and that too last year. Did it take you longer than usual to
>   obtain the visa after refusal? My husband's passport bag did not even
>   contain a letter of refusal, and the reason for refusal – Hafsa
>   yesterday
>
> No it didn't take longer.. We applied with valid supported documents
>   as a evidence which made our case stronger the next time.. Very
>   unusual thing is happen with u that u didn't get the refusal letter
>   and the valid reason why they refuse you.. Better you ask a new
>   question here so the expertise may advice you ehat to do next – maya
>   sheikh 3 hours ago

Source: [Uk visa got refused due to unexplained deposits. How to re-apply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50590/uk-visa-got-refused-planning-to-re-apply) (in comments)

---

Based upon your refusal notice, they suspect you tried a parking strategy and were planning to abscond when you arrived in the UK ([Paragraph V 4.2 of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)).  A definition and description of funds parking is given [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158) , and your narrative explains that you are now aware of what they are looking for and know how to avoid this kind of refusal.

There's additional information about the "provenance of funds" for you in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-source-of-evidence-of-funds).

**Will they want to know why he did not mention his other account in the previous application?**

There is no hard requirement for this, but it would be prudent to offer something as they mentioned this explicitly in the refusal notice.  Generally it's best practices to explain everything mentioned in a previous refusal.

**Is there anything else we need to attach with the application this time?**

If you are taking your daughter out of school, you should include something from the school, otherwise your list looks fine.

**Will it take longer than usual now?**

Yes, but not significantly.  You will be able to meet a December travel date if you apply later this month.

**Any suggestions in this regard will be really helpful.**

The best suggestion is to have your application examined by a UK based solicitor before you submit it. This is not necessary but constitutes a best practices approach following a refusal.  You will have to pay a fee, and I would ask your husband's employer to expense the fees for this because they are putting him in the course.  You can find a list of practitioners at the [Immigration Law Practitioners' Association](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/).

Their [info sheet on the visitor rules](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/resources.php/30883/information-sheet_-visitors-new-immigration-rules) is great research material. I suggest downloading and studying it.

Comment: So is it not unusual to not receive a letter of refusal with the passport? We have no doubt that his visa got refused as well, because the reason was detailed out in my refusal letter, which was enclosed with my passport. And if he re-applies, can this create any problem? Like I mentioned earlier, there is no stamp on his passport regarding the current processing of application.