# UK visa refusal for undocumented deposits?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My short term study visa was refused and the only cause mentioned in the letter was the presence of undocumented old deposits in the bank transactions. I haven't explained the deposits as they are old and have entered and exited the account long ago (no longer in my balance). Now I am planning to apply again but I am so afraid of having a second refusal.

How can I explain the deposits? Most of them are from one friend. I will explain that they are an old debt and my friend has returned it to me via multiple deposits. I will let him sign a paper confirming this. Will this be enough?

Also, I was afraid of other reasons that they did not mention at all in the refusal letter. Can they refuse me for other reason that they didn't explain in the first refusal?

Comment: [related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50590/8105)